# Java library for creating videos

Tags: java, video

I would like to know where to find third-party java libraries, specifically I'm looking for something that could generate a video from photos, something like power point but for videos... Any suggestion?

Comment: You should write your question in english. Usted debe escribir su pregunta en Inglés.

Comment: I've edited the question with a Google Translated version, it might not be 100% accurate. Anyone speaking Spanish to refine it?

Comment: @Pascal Thivent, it seems okay, I just hope the OP speaks english.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) is an abandoned Sun API that is capable of turning images into MOV format video.

JMF provides some sample code called [JpegImagesToMovie](http://www.koders.com/java/fid8AE9208DC5FB846910DFD3F935D64E7C9A5BB784.aspx)(1) that did just that, but it assumed that each JPEG was a single image in a constant frame rate animation.  In other words, if the animation was to display one image for two seconds, then spend the next second fading into the next image, and the end result was to be replayed at 10 FPS, then it would take 30 images.  It would be the programmer's responsibility to provide the individual images, and image transition frames.

(1) I'd have linked to the Sun version, but since the changeover to Oracle, all the JMF sample code seems to have disappeared.